# va_list arguments not working as expected

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

I've been tracing a problem that I've narrowed down to this skeleton:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct __log_file_details {                           
    FILE  *fp ;                                               
    char  *name ;                                             
} log_file_details_t;

typedef struct __log_files {                                  
    char               is_open;                              
    log_file_details_t lf[3];
    void               (*open_log)(struct __log_files *ctl);
    void               (*close_log)(struct __log_files *ctl);
    } log_files_t ;                                           

int write_log(const int file_nbr, log_files_t *ctl, char *log_this, ...);
void close_log(log_files_t *ctl);
void open_log(log_files_t *ctl);              

// Here we go...                                                                                 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    log_files_t log_ctl = {
        0,
        { {NULL, NULL}, {NULL, NULL}, {NULL, NULL} },
        &open_log,
        &close_log
    };                                           

    write_log(0, &log_ctl, "foo"); // That's it.

    return 0;
}

void open_log(log_files_t *ctl) {}
void close_log(log_files_t *ctl) {}

int write_log(const int file_nbr, log_files_t *ctl, char *log_this, ...)
{
    int rc;
    /* ... */
    rc = 0;
}
```

When I compile this code using `gdb -g -o foo foo.c` it works on most of my linux systems.

However, I have an ARM device (actually, a Netgear Stora running Linux) on which it fails miserably.
On that device, if I use GDB to step through this code, when `write_log` executes (line 58), I see:

> `Breakpoint 1, write(log(file_nbr=-1092220616, ctl=0x0, log_this=0xbee60ac4 "-garbage-") at foo.c:58`

(where `-1092220616` is a varying value, and `-garbage-` tends to contain a bunch of control characters.)

I don't know how to determine if this is a runtime problem (one of the libraries?), a problem with one of the standard headers, a gcc problem, or something else. What might I do in order to identify and resolve this problem?

If I remove the va_list definition of write_log, all works well, but of course that's not what I want.)

Comment: Could you please complete the code? So that it at least includes the va_list you mentioned

Comment: And is the definition of log_ctl really in the local variables of the function main, and not say, some other function which is left after the pointer to log_ctl is stored somewhere (in which case it is expected to contain ... something unexpected)

Comment: @Dennis Does _"fail miserably"_ mean that you see "garbage" in GDB, or does it also do some undesired behavior, like crash? The garbage may very well mean that GDB is not displaying the variadic parameters properly, that's all...

Comment: This code is complete; I have trimmed it down to this in order to provide a minimal, failing program.

Comment: You really shouldn't name your structs like that.  C reserves external identifiers starting with an underscore and _all_ names starting with an underscore and uppercase letter or starting with two underscores for the compiler and library to use.

Comment: @epheient - thanks for your comment  When I get home, I will ammend that.  Do you have any response to the question?

Comment: @EitanT - "Fails miserably" as a result of ctl pointing to 0x0. In the big picture, reference to ctl->anything causes a crash.  It's not only misrepresenting "foo" - it is misrepresenting all three parameters.  On other systems, gdb shows me what I expect (0, valid pointer, valid pointer with value "foo").

Comment: @Dennis I took the liberty to format your code a little bit to make it slightly more readable. Did you look at `&log_ctl` and verify that it is non-zero before `write_log()` executes?

Comment: @Dennis: where is your use of va_list?

Comment: @EitanT: Why would the address of a local variable ever be NULL?

Comment: Let me guess, the real value of `&log_ctl` is `0xbee60ac4`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Beats me. Maybe he has a memory overrun. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Dennis No, not in the code as shown.

Comment: @ALL - Code is complete, designed to get to the heart of the matter: unexpected result when calling a procedure with, effectively, hardcoded values. Result is that values are changed at instantiation (or whetever the correct term is).  There's no hidden code, nothing else is needed for this to fail on the "bad" platform.  Of course, the program from which this is extracted is considerably more complex, but you don't want/need that for this purpose!  I just need to know how to find out what is the source of this problem. BTW: In my testing, I have tried the STRUCT outside of main: no change.

Comment: @Dennis: stdarg routines were designed to access the _stack_. You can do very interesting things with them. That's why people want to know exactly how are you using them. For instance: not all stacks grow up (or was it down?).

Comment: @Dennis are you sure what you are seeing isn't some problem of gdb/compiler optimization for the stubbed function that you show here?  

Could you show the original problem and code that was the source of your frustration?

Comment: @Pablitorun, Lacking any optimization switches, I would not expect this to be such a result, but it could be.  The code is actually spread across six modules that are quite complex, and include some business confidential code.  Anyway, isn't it moot?  Why do you need something else that fails when we can see the fundamental failure here?  Will it be easier to resolve if we throw lots of other stuff into the mix?  How does <i>that</i> work?

Comment: @Dennis: Just to clarify, is the symptom merely a debugger weirdness, or if you do (for example), `printf("%d\n", file_nbr)` inside `write_log()`, do you get the wrong result displayed?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - it is the latter. In fact, the first thing the full version of write_log does, is to check ctl->is_open. In every case, it is neither 0 nor 1, although those are the only values to which it is ever set. Also, the addresses of ctl->open() and ctl->close() are garbage, which is of course fatal.  When I get back to this later today, I will provide a debug session that shows the issue.

Comment: Hmmm... my debug session told me I don't know what I'm talking about, and that it is a gdb anomaly.  I'm so embarrassed!  So after a couple more hours of fighting with it, I finally moved the entire codeset and sample data to another system.  There, I analyzed the problem and easily(!) found that my issue was completely unrelated to the demonstrated code.  Problem was similar to: printf("%s", a, b), where a mismatch in format string and variable count bit me.  I regret wasting so many peoples' time.

Answer (score -2):

You need to properly clean up the variable args in your function:

```
int write_log(const int file_nbr, log_files_t *ctl, char *log_this, ...)
{
    int rc;

    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,log_this);

    /* ... */

    va_end(vl);

    rc = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should this affect the argument values?